How can I display published date as time and date difference in blog post on WordPress with divi theme?
I want to show 'time ago '(eg. 2 days ago) instead of the published date on the WordPress blog setting on the Divi theme. I am a beginner working on WordPress.
I tried searching on the Internet but couldn't find a solution to this problem.

There are a few places in Divi that the published date is shown, including: standard posts, archive pages (categories, search, etc), the post title module, and the blog module. Do you know which of these it is you want to change? Each will probably have at least a slightly different solution (and I think all of them will require custom code). If you are able to identify which of these places you want to modify, or share a link to an example page, that should help narrow with getting you a solution.

I am trying to make this change ( 'published date' to 'time ago') on the blog module. Sorry for the incomplete information. How can I solve this?

Blog module of Divi theme does not have the option for this. Divi blog module has options for Date Format where you can change how the date displays. M=month, j=date, and Y=year.
But to fulfill your requirement you need to make changes to Blog Module or need to create new module, here is the guide for you.
https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/developers/divi-module/how-to-create-a-divi-builder-module/
While making changes you can use the human_time_diff() function of PHP for this.
<?php
// To print an entry's time (eg.: "1 day ago"): 
echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago';
?>

